# How to apply borders when printing DataFrame in CLI?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to separate the DataFrame cells with something like │ and ─.

This is the code at the moment

```
game_board = [
    [" ", "X", " ", "X", " ", "X", " ", "X"],
    ["X", " ", "X", " ", "X", " ", "X", " "],
    [" ", "X", " ", "X", " ", "X", " ", "X"],
    [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
    [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
    ["O", " ", "O", " ", "O", " ", "O", " "],
    [" ", "O", " ", "O", " ", "O", " ", "O"],
    ["O", " ", "O", " ", "O", " ", "O", " "]
]
print DataFrame(game_board)
```

and this is the output:
[image]

How does one add borders to DataFrame inside CLI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `tabulate` package:

```
pip install tabulate
```

---

Call `tabulate.tabulate` with `tablefmt='grid'`, to get neat squares around your frame elements.

```
import tabulate

df = pd.DataFrame(game_board)
print(tabulate.tabulate(df, tablefmt='grid', showindex=False))

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | X |   | X |   | X |   | X |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| X |   | X |   | X |   | X |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | X |   | X |   | X |   | X |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| O |   | O |   | O |   | O |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | O |   | O |   | O |   | O |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| O |   | O |   | O |   | O |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: @MaxU Thank you! I took a pot shot at this myself and this was my best guess.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. On a side note though, any chance to remove the grid around line numbers? (would be nice to do, not required tho)